# Symfony won't accept dates between 12/12/any year - 31/12/any year

Tags: symfony

Symfony won't accept dates between **12/12/any year - 31/12/any year** as date and produce error below.

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (31/12/1111) at position 0 (3): Unexpected character
```

Any reason why?

**Note**: Some will ask why I don't use line below. I don't use because I don't want form validation errors coming from form type. I'm purely reliying on annotations. If anyone knows how to by-pass form validation errors coming from form type then I'm happy to lear and use it instead.

```
$builder->add('year', 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
```

**Cars Entity:**

```
/**
 * @var date
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The Year field is required.")
 */
protected $year;
```

**Form type:**

```
->add('year', 'text', array('label' => 'Year'))
```

**Controller**

```
$cars->setYear(new \DateTime($formdata->getYear()));
```

Comment: Is "12/12" itself considered an error, or is it actually "13/12"? The latter is invalid (all the way up to "31/12" if the month is expected first.

Comment: 25/11/2014, 31/12/2014 etc are all considered as an error for some reason so anything between 12-31 as in days (never mind the months and years) are invalid. I don't know why!

Comment: Uh, sure. Does it work if you think of the first number as the **month** and the second of the **day**? That was the gist of my question.

Comment: Do they work if you use dashes instead of slashes (`12-12-2014`, `31-12-2014`, etc)? Or maybe add `'input' => 'datetime'`?

Comment: Qoop - When I use dash instead of slash it works but I need slash.  Jongware - Yes changing day and month order worked as well. The question is, How can I force it to accept dd/mm/yyyy version?

Comment: Note: I don't want validation messages coming from the form type though.

Comment: Why are you using the year `1111`? That can also cause problems since most *nix systems count time in seconds using [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Which means any date before 1970 would be invalid to PHP.

Comment: 2014 won't work either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), you should change this line

```
$cars->setYear(new \DateTime($formdata->getYear()));
```

to this

```
$cars->setYear(\DateTime::createFromFormat('j/m/Y', $formdata->getYear()));
```

Comment: Ahaaaa, it worked. What a weird way of handling thing nowadays! Anyway, thanks for it.

Comment: @MadMax No problem! [There's a reason why Y-m-d is the accepted standard](http://xkcd.com/1340/)

Comment: I'm storing the date as in `Y-m-d` but letting users type in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. They more comfortable with it so.